# How do you use Jackson InjectableValues?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

Trying to use `InjectableValues` in Jackson deserialization to gain control over object instantiation.

My `InjectableValues` instance never gets called. Jackson versions 2.0.5, 2.9.1, and a few in between.

Other than that, it works correctly (reads json to java).
Here is the test code:

```
ObjectMapper createMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper = mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper = mapper.setInjectableValues(injectableValues());
    return mapper;
}

InjectableValues injectableValues() {
    return new InjectableValues() {
        @Override
        public Object findInjectableValue(Object id, DeserializationContext ctx, BeanProperty prop, Object parent) {
            final Class<?> clazz = prop.getType().getRawClass();
            System.out.println("Inject " + clazz);
            try {
                return clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}

public void testLoad(String json) throws Exception{
    Object obj = createMapper().readValue(json, A.class);
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Also tried setting it explicitly on the `ObjectReader`:

```
createMapper().reader(A.class)
.with(injectableValues()).readValue(json);
```

Comment: Can you post your A class, because you have to annotate the field that you are trying to inject with `@JacksonInject`.

Comment: Thanks. The objects are plain POJOs with no annotations. Is there a way to gain control on object instantiation of every object, regardless of annotation?

Comment: Could you please explain, what you would like to achieve? Maybe `InjectableValues` is not the best option in your case. Do you want to force it to create class `A` by calling `newInstance()` method?